# Math.ceil(00.1); Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, ceil

I was debugging on chrome console and found this error. Basically,

```js
Math.ceil(0.1); // Works
Math.ceil(00.1); // Doesn't work
```

Any reason / thoughts for this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `00.1` supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal literals can only start with a *single* `0`. From [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-NumericLiteral), a *NumericLiteral* is a *DecimalLiteral*, *BinaryIntegerLiteral*, *OctalIntegerLiteral*, or *HexIntegerLiteral*. Yours is a *DecimalLiteral* because it includes a `.`. That can have only one leading zero.

Here are the linked rules:

> NumericLiteral::
>
> DecimalLiteral
>   
>      BinaryIntegerLiteral
>   
>      OctalIntegerLiteral
>   
>      HexIntegerLiteral

Yours is a *DecimalLiteral* because of the `.`, which is:

> DecimalLiteral::
>
> DecimalIntegerLiteral . DecimalDigits<sub>opt</sub> ExponentPart<sub>opt</sub>
>   
>      . DecimalDigits<sub>opt</sub> ExponentPart<sub>opt</sub>
>   
>      DecimalIntegerLiteral ExponentPart<sub>opt</sub>

...where

> DecimalIntegerLiteral::
>
> 0
>   
>      NonZeroDigit DecimalDigits<sub>opt</sub>

and

> DecimalDigits::
>
> DecimalDigit
>   
>      DecimalDigits DecimalDigit

and

> DecimalDigit:: **one of**
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: I'm curious...any idea why JS throws this specific error in the OP's case? I'm just curious as to why JS thinks a closing parenthesis is missing.

Comment: My understanding is that parser gets confused by the syntax and basically consumes the rest of the string (including the closing parenthesis). And that means it never goes out of 'looking for the end of arguments definition' state, which triggers the error.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie: The paren is missing after the `00`. `00` is interpreted as an integer literal, the `.` as method call syntax, but then it sees the `1` (which is not a legal method name). Since it was expecting a close paren eventually, and the code went off the rails when you tried to "call" `1` on it, it seems to backtrack and say "you probably missed a paren after the `00`". You can get a similar error (`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`) doing just `00.1;` (or `foo.1;` for any old object), for roughly the same reasons.